# Is there a closed form for the sum $\sum_{k = 0}^{n} {n \choose k}(2k)! x^k$?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, closed-form

I came across this sum while studying a problem in graph theory, and I'm trying to find a good upper bound. Replacing $(2k)!$ with $(2n)!$ is too coarse for what I need, so I'd like to find some more accurate way to bound the sum. If it helps, here $x = \frac{\log n}{2n^2}$.

I tried Stirling, but I can't figure out how to get anything meaningful out of a sum with $k^k$. I also tried snake oil on $n$, but I still end up with a $(2k)!$ in the sum that I don't know how to deal with.

Are there any identities that might be useful here? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You could write it as a hypergeometric expression: $${\mbox{$_3$F$_0$}({\frac{1}{2}},1,-n;\,\ ;\,-4\,x)}$$

Comment: Have you checked how the summand behaves with respect to $k$? For example, perhaps it is unimodal and thus peaks around $k=n/2$. (This comment is only about the bound, not a closed form for the sum.)

Comment: Typically closed forms of these type of sums can obtain by repeatedly differentiating an appropriate "binomial expansion."

Comment: Thank you to everyone for the suggestions.

I should check more closely where the sum peaks. Initially, my intuition told me that the largest terms occur when $k$ is close to $n$, but looking at it again, I'm not so sure.

I don't see how this sum could come from a binomial expansion. How many times would one take the derivative? Some function of $k$ times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the Euler integral
$$
(2k)! = \int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - t} t^{2k} dt} ,
$$
whence
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\binom{n}{k}(2k)!x^k } & = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\binom{n}{k}\int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - t} t^{2k} dt} x^k }  = \int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - t} \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\binom{n}{k}(t^2 x)^k } dt} 
\\ & = \int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - t} (1 + t^2 x)^n dt} .
\end{align*}
Perhaps this form can be used to obtain better bounds.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. This turned out to be exactly what I needed. Köszönöm szépen =)